# VBA - Generate Excel File from Access (QueryTable)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, stored-procedures

I have a project that basically the goal is to generate Excel (Report) starting the Click of a button in Access using VBA.

The contents of this report is the result of a Stored Procedure SQL Server Database.

the line of error:

```
With MeuExcel.Worksheets(4)
    .QueryTables.Add connection:=rs, Destination:=.Range("A2")
End With
```

I get is:

```
invalid procedure call or argument (erro '5')
```

Complete Code (Edited using Remou User tips):

```
Sub GeraPlanilhaDT()

Dim MeuExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As New Excel.Workbook

Set MeuExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
MeuExcel.Workbooks.Add

MeuExcel.Visible = True

Dim strNomeServidor, strBaseDados, strProvider, strConeccao, strStoredProcedure As String

strNomeServidor = "m98\DES;"
strBaseDados = "SGLD_POC;"
strProvider = "SQLOLEDB.1;"
strStoredProcedure = "SP_ParametrosLeads_DT"

strConeccao = "Provider=" & strProvider & "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=" & strNomeServidor & "Initial Catalog=" & strBaseDados

Dim cnt As New ADODB.connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.command
Dim rs As New ADODB.recordset
Dim prm As New ADODB.parameter

cnt.Open strConeccao

cmd.ActiveConnection = cnt
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = strStoredProcedure
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("DT", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm 
cmd.Parameters("DT").Value = InputBox("Digite o Código DT", "Código do Distribuidor")

Set rs = cmd.Execute()

Dim nomeWorksheetPrincipal As String
nomeWorksheetPrincipal = "Principal"

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = nomeWorksheetPrincipal



With MeuExcel.Worksheets(4)
    .QueryTables.Add connection:=rs, Destination:=.Range("A2")
End With


cnt.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set strNomeServidor = Nothing
Set strBaseDados = Nothing
Set strProvider = Nothing

If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then
    FormataDadosTabela
Else
    MsgBox ("Não foi encontrado nenhum Distribuidor com esse DT")
End If


End Sub
```

The strange thing is that the code works when run in Excel but does not work in Access

Comment: Okay, like you, I now have code that works in Excel but does not work in Access. There seems to be a problem adding query tables. I cannot see why as yet. I wonder if an alternative solution would suit? For example, would simply writing the records to a worksheet be suitable?

Comment: FYI: I have automated Excel Querytables from Access for years without problem, albeit with Access data as the source. However, I have not tried it in Office 2010.

Comment: @Rachel Perhaps you could post some working Access code?

Comment: @Remou  I updated my answer with sample code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

In Access, you need to prefix the Excel application objects with the Excel application instance, for example:

```
With MeuExcel.Worksheets(4).QueryTables.Add( _
    connection:=recordset, _
    Destination:=Range("A2"))
End With
```

Furthermore, unless you have a reference to the Excel library, ypu will need to provide the value for built-in Excel constants.

It is a very bad idea to use the name of objects for variables. Do not say:

```
Dim recordset As recordset
Set recordset = New recordset
```

Say, for example:

```
Dim rs As recordset
```

Or much better:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
```

If you have a suitable reference. You can then skip CreateObject.

**EDIT**

The provider must be the Access OLEDB 10 provider, as used to bind recordsets. This works for me to create a data table via Access using SQL Server:

```
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=True;" _
& "Data Source=XYZ\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
& "Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, two things stand out:

1. As @Remou pointed out, Excel references need to be qualified. Currently, `Range("A2")` is unqualified. When running the code in Excel, the `ActiveSheet` is assumed. However, when running from another application, that application will look for a method or property in its own library called `Range`, which will give you that error in Microsoft Access.
2. There isn't any code in the `With` block, so you can remove the `With` and `End With` keywords; when you do this also remove the outer (), like this:

`wb.Worksheets(4).QueryTables.Add Connection:=rs, Destination:=wb.Worksheets(4).Range("A2")`

Alternatively, shift the `With` block to the `Worksheet` level:

```
With wb.Worksheets(4)
    .QueryTables.Add Connection:=rs, Destination:=.Range("A2")
End With
```

---

**Update—Access to Excel Sample**

This sample code automates Excel from Access, creating a new workbook and adding a Querytable to the first sheet. The source data is an Access table. This runs in Office 2007.

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel()
  Dim appXL As Excel.Application
  Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
  Dim wst As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  appXL.Visible = True
  Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks.Add
  Set wst = wbk.Worksheets(1)

  Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM tblTemp"
    .Open
  End With

  With wst
    .QueryTables.Add Connection:=rs, Destination:=.Range("A1")
    .QueryTables(1).Refresh
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: @Predoff  I modified my example to substitute the ``Workbook`` object for the ``Excel Application`` object. Not sure if this will resolve your problem, but it is more correct.

Comment: @Rachel I have also tried to get this to work, and I am fairly sure there is a problem with running in Access. A worksheet that accepts data still will not allow QueryTables.Add, it fails with error 5, as stated by Predoff. The example I used worked perfectly in Excel and was taken from MSDN.

Comment: That works perfectly with 2010, so should be the solution for @Predoff. I must check where the difference lies!

Comment: It appears to be in the connection string, though why I do not yet see, because the connection string I used produced a perfectly valid recordset.

Comment: I have found it is the Provider that is the problem. I have added a note to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what Office version, but in Excel 2007/10 a QueryTable is a property of a Listobject so your code would be like:

```
With MeuExcel.Worksheets.ListObjects.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A2")).QueryTable
```

Comment: After re-reading the question, I realize that this isn't the issue - as you have a runtime error.  I think @RachelHettinger (as usual) has hit the nail on the head.